# How to set parameterized value in Postgres SELECT query using WHERE condition

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am very new to PostgreSQL please bear with me.

I need to read records from the table using select query with where condition.

```
  Eg: select * from switch where switchId=10;
```

QueryFactory.js

```
  let queryMap = {
        “getSwitchInfo”: ‘select * from switch where switchId=?’
  }

  module.exports=queryMap;
```

Controller.js

```
 let client = require(rootdir+’dao/postgresSQL’);
 let queryFactory = require(rootdir+’/dao/QueryFactory’);

 let query = queryFactory.getQuery(“getSwitchInfo”);

 let switchId = req.query.switchId;
 client.query(query, function(err, res){
         if(err){

          }
 });
```

Please see:- this switchId value 10 I get from client and using query parameter I am getting it in my node backend layer.

Kindly suggest how can I pass switchId to the query as a parameterized value.

Comment: I have updated the code. Kindly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself for this issue. Added params to an array and passed this array as a second param to client.query method and in the query where condition I added $1. It is working fine now

QueryFactory.js

```
  let queryMap = {
    “getSwitchInfo”: ‘select * from switch where switchId=$1’
  }

  module.exports=queryMap;
```

Controller.js

```
  let params = [req.query.switchId];
     client.query(query, params, function(err, res){
         if(err){

         }
   });
```